# Quickest way to turn multidimensional array into List?

Tags: php

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [categoryid] => 60
            [categoryName] => Parent Category A
            [categoryParent] => 
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [categoryid] => 65
            [categoryName] => Parent Category B
            [categoryParent] => 
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [categoryid] => 68
            [categoryName] => Child Category A
            [categoryParent] => 65
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [categoryid] => 69
            [categoryName] => Super Child Category A
            [categoryParent] => 68
        )
)
```

I need to end up with a list like this:

- Parent Category A
- Parent Category B

  - Child Category A

    - Super Child Category A

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: use recursive foreach loop.

Comment: I would first ensure that you've got an actual tree (ie. flatten it), that will make it easier to process. So the ones with `categoryParent` are mapped as an array of children. Then use a foreach loop that goes down grabbing the children of each if it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function htmlList($array, $parent = null){
    $str = '<ul>';
    foreach($array as $object){
        if(!$parent){
            if(!$object->categoryParent){ 
                $str .= '<li>' . $object->categoryName;
                $str .= htmlList($array, $object->categoryid);
                $str .=  '</li>';
            }
        }
    }
    return $str .= '</ul>';
}

echo htmlList($yourArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function mylist( $a, $parent='') {
   $r = '' ;
   foreach ( $a as $i ) {
       if ($i['categoryParent'] == $parent ) {
          $r = $r . "<li>" . $i['categoryName'] . mylist( $a, $i['categoryid'] ) . "</li>";
       }
   }
   return ($r==''?'':"<ul>". $r . "</ul>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to keep a array with parent items, and add the subitems in a own array of the element. (Similar to your tree)

You can read this element by following example:

```
<?php
BuildList($arrayParent, 0);

function BuildList($arrayElements, $depth)
{
    foreach($arrayElements as $element)
    {
        echo str_repeat("&nbsp;&nbsp;", $depth) . $element->categoryName;
        $depth++;
        if(count($element->subCategory) > 0)
            $depth = BuildList($element->subCategory, $depth);

        return $depth;
    }
}
?>
```